# python virtualenv instance is broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I was using a python3.6.5 virtualenv however it started to show the following error message when I try to run any pip and python methods. I know I can look into site-packages to capture the installed packages and rebuild the virtualenv, however was wondering if there are better ways of salvaging this:

```
pip freeze > /tmp/requirements.txt
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv36/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 703, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv36/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 683, in main
    paths_in_sys = addsitepackages(paths_in_sys)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv36/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 282, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv36/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 204, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv36/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 173, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 568, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Comment: do you try to run `pip` inside your venv (`/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv36/bin/pip`)?

Comment: yes the environment is activated, so either pip or running python generates the posted error